# Conditional comparison between columns from two pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two files, one with data and one file for comparison.
In File 1 there are two columns; element with the name of the element, and A with the value.
In File 2 there are threshold values for the same elements, although their names are slightly different, and the order is not the same.

What I want to do is to search for the elements in File 1, in File 2. When there's a match between the elements, I'll compare the values in File 1 with the threshold values in File 2. I can do that with str.match or str.contains, however these only return True/False, and don't allow me to continue working. I tried a for-loop with the in operator, however this only works if the order of the elements is the same in both files. And, I've understood that I should avoid for loops with data frames.

```
 for j in File2['element']:
            if j in File1['element']:
                print(j)
```

What is the best way to solve this?

File 1:

```
element A    
aa    6.2        
bb    3.1        
cc    4.7
```

File 2 for comparison:

```
element     D   E   F        
bb(b)       1   2   3           
aa(a)       1   5   10        
cc(c)      10   20  30
```

Comment: what a result do you expect with that data?

Comment: I expect to get a pdf where the values in file 1 are marked with for example a color depending on which interval they fall within, defined by the columns in file 2

Answer (score 0):

Start from a slight change in *file_2*.
I mean extracting the "first part" of *element* (before the opening parenthesis)
and setting it as the index:

```
file_2.set_index(file_2.element.str.extract(r'(?P<elem>\w+)').elem, inplace=True)
```

Then you can:

- set *element* in *file_1* as the index,
- moin both files,
- maybe drop *element* column (originating from *file_2*).

The code to do it is:

```
file_1.set_index('element').join(file_2, how='left')\
    .drop(columns=['element'])
```

Now you have:

```
           A   D   E   F
element                 
aa       6.2   1   5  10
bb       3.1   1   2   3
cc       4.7  10  20  30
```

where:

- the key is the *element* name,
- *A* is the original column from *file_1*,
- all remaining columns are from *file_2*.

This way you are not limited by the order of rows in *file_2*.

Then, for each row, you can perform some comparison between *A*
and renaining columns.